# C++: проблема с указателями

Tags: c++, указатели

Хочу перейти к другому значению через добавление константы к указателю, но выводит не то значение, что нужно.

```
int min(int m, ...) {
    int *ptr = &m;
    int min = *(ptr + 1);
    if (*ptr == 0)
        return 0;
    for(; *ptr; ptr++) {
        if (*ptr < min)
            min = *ptr;
    }
    return min;
}
```

`*ptr` работает нормально, но уже `*(ptr + 1)` не выдаёт то, что нужно.

Comment: а что вы в аргументе m передаёте?

Comment: количество параметров

Comment: и куда по Вашему должно указывать &m + 1 ? :)

Comment: ну я потом в функцию указываю параметры и хочу через *(ptr++) переходить од одного парамeтра к другому. ето функции со сменным количеством параметров.

Comment: @day4me, так, к сожалению, не будет работать. Можно использовать [`va_arg`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic/va_arg), либо написать шаблонную функцию с переменным числом параметров, например [такую](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16663866/variadic-templates-sum-operation-left-associative).

Comment: Так тоже будет, но stdarg, всё же, предпочтительнее. 
А почему не ptr++ в min?

Comment: а как мне через va_arg присвоить int min первый элемент чтоб потом искать min элемент?

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n что вы имеете в виду,   min = ptr++ или min =*ptr++?

Comment: @day4me перемещать указатель, не значение: min = ptr++

Comment: @day4me, зачем вам присваивать минимуму первый элемент, есть же прекрасный [`numer_limits<int>::min`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/min).

Comment: @n3r0bi0m4n, если честно, сомневаюсь, что так будет работать, имхо, `*(&m + 1)` — [*undefined behaviour*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Неопределённое_поведение).

Comment: @Дмитрий это я чтобы словами не писать "указатель на следующий элемент"

Comment: а если так написть int min(int min, ...)
{
int m=min;
int *ptr=&min;                         
if(*ptr==0)return 0;
for(;*ptr;ptr++){
if(*ptr<m) 
m=*ptr;
}
return m;
}

Comment: всем спасибо, сделал через va_arg :)

Comment: @day4me: Что значит "хочу переходить од одного парамeтра к другому"? Языку малоинтерено, что вы "хотите". Ни о каком переходе "от одного параметра к другому" при помощи такого указателя не может быть и речи. Такой возможности в языке нет и никогда не было. Доступ к `...` параметрам в языке делается через `va_list`. Других способов нет.

Comment: @AnT Ну, если человек из львовской политехники... Уже была как-то беседа, человека убедили, что нужны `va_arg`, но у него препод - автор учебника по C++ (в котором все ссылки не на стандарт, а на Borlabd C++ 3.1), в котором написано - через указатели, и который требовал от студентов - только указатели...

Answer (score 1):

Если всё-таки интересует, почему не получалось с указателями, возможно, это подскажет почему.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LIMIT 100

void searchoffset(int findwhat, ...)
{
   int *args = &findwhat;
   printf("first element: %p : %d\n\n", args, *args);
   args++;
   int counter = 0;

   do
   {
      printf("offset: %d [%p : %d]\n", counter, args, *args);
      args++;
      counter++;
   } while (*args != findwhat);

   printf("offset: %d [%p : %d]\n", counter, args, *args);
}


int main()
{
   searchoffset(135, 2, 11, 144, 25, 7, 135);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: может проблема в компиляторе?

Comment: у меня. : )))))

Comment: @day4me, проблема в том, что нельзя разыменовывать указатель, следующий/предыдущий за указателем `&m` (где `m` — первый аргумент функции). Точнее это является неопределённым поведением. То есть вы, конечно, можете его разыменовать в вашей программе, но это скорее всего не будет работать, а если и будет, то это случайность (и может перестать работать в любой момент).

Comment: ну есть же способ добавления констант к указателю, и тогда можна преходить между ячейкми памяти.